# How can I change the style of selected date in react-native-calendar-stripe

Tags: javascript, react-native, styles

I set Button to show calendar and when press this Button and select a date this shows in the calendar -strip located at the top. problem is that the style changes just for the pre-selected date and when I select the new date the style is not function.

this is my code:

> ```
>  <CalendarStrip
>                     scrollable
>                     style={{ height: 70, paddingBottom: 10 }}
>                     calendarColor={'#4caf50'}
>                     selectedDate={new Date(date)}
>                     calendarHeaderStyle={{ display: "none" }}
>                     iconStyle={{ display: "none" }}
>                     highlightDateNameStyle={{ color: 'black', position: "absolute", bottom: 
>                      10, color: 'green', backgroundColor: "white" }}
>                     highlightDateNumberStyle={{ color: 'green', padding: 10, borderRadius: 6, 
>                      backgroundColor: "white" }}
>                     dateNumberStyle={{ color: 'white', borderRadius: 6, }}
>                     dateNameStyle={{ color: 'white', position: "absolute", bottom: 0.5 }}
>                     iconContainer={{ flex: 0.1 }}
>                 />
>               {show && (
>                 <DateTimePicker
>                     testID="dateTimePicker"
>                     value={new Date()}
>                     mode={mode}
>                     is24Hour={true}
>                     display="default"
>                     onChange={onChange}
>                 />
>             )}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

1- In `DateTimePicker` you have `onChange` prop, so make onChange function set the selected value.

2- Now in `CalendarStrip` let the prop `selectedDate` take the value you have set in onChange

Comment: This prop is ok when I select a date on calender-strip. but I want to select a date from another calendar and show it in calender-strip. the external calendar is connected to the calendar strip and shows it as my selected date but the format does not change . for example when I select a date from an external calendar the background color of selected date in strip is not change